# Data Base Schema, should I change my table structure for performance?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am building an application with the following tables and I am looking for some recomendations on my DB schema (PostgreSQL): I have a central product table, a store table and I need a table with the prices of each product on each store. Prices are updated daily and I must keep the history for further analysis. Prices come from a crawler that fetches data from each product url

```
Table_products:
    product_id
    name
    category
    description
    attribute_1
    attribute_2

Table_Store:
    store_id
    name
    url

Table_product_store
    product_id
    store_id
    product_url

Table_price
    Product_id
    Store_id
    Price
    Availability
    Timestamp
```

I wonder if this structure make sense or if I could improve it. Considering that the user will consult historic price for each product. That is the main feature. Would it be a good idea to use materialized view for table_price? I would refresh it once a day with new prices.

Comment: How would you plan to use that materialized view? Denormalizing database will increase performance for SELECT but increase work on those that modify data as you would need mechanisms that keep data integrity.

If performance is a concern then consider partitioning `Table_price`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am planing to use a view to join Table_price with Table_products and display product and price information within the webapp. Since that will be the main feature, My concern is that querying this view on every request would be bad for performance, so I would create a materialized view for that. Does it make sense?

Comment: Materialized view will make select statements faster. It will however cost some time and computing to update such view so depending on how this database is going to be used it could be good or bad approach.